# What does &H57 represent and how can I translate it for C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, syntax

I'm trying to convert old VB.NET code into C# and I'm not sure about the current line and what it means really.

VB.NET:

```
Const REQUEST_EFI As Byte = &H57
```

What would this be in c#?  I tried:

```
const byte request_efi = &H57;
```

But it says

> "H57 is not part of the current
>   context".

First of all, how is &H57 a byte?  Second, it seems that the & operator has a different representation in this context aside from concatenation.  Third obviously being, how the heck do I re-write this for C#? lol.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it is a hexadecimal number. The syntax for that would be `0x57` in C#.

Answer (score 3):

`&H57` is a way to represent hex numbers in VB, so the C# equivalent would be:

```
const byte request_efi = 0x57;
```

Answer (score 2):

&H## is how VB represents hexadecimal numbers. In this case it is the hex number 57 or 87 in decimal. the C# equivalent would be:

```
const byte request_efi = 0x57;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hexadecimal representation of the 87.
Use `const byte request_efi = 0x57;` or `const byte request_efi = 87;`

Answer (score -1):

It's the letter W for crying out loud

Comment: Actually it isn't. The original VB code is storing the hexadecimal value in a `Byte`. Both VB6 and VB.net store `Char`s as Unicode - 2 bytes per character. They do not use ASCII, even though the character codes line up for the first 128 characters.